# Adding table to existing ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an existing site using ASP.NET and EF, with SQL Server.  I need to add a new unrelated table to the DB.  I've done this in VS while building a site, and used the "Update Model from Database" tool (I'm using "DB First" if that matters) but never tried doing it once the site is deployed and running.  Can I just add the table using SSMS against the remote host, and then update the site with the corresponding changes?

Thanks!

Comment: If the table is unrelated, should it really be in this db?  Short answer: yes, you can create the table with SSMS.  Longer Answer: if you care about uptime, work out the details in a test environment first.  Recommendation: use  [SSDT](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/ssdt/) to create a database project from your existing database and modify/add tables in the project.  Use schema compare to create an update script or run the update tool (on test first, then live).

Comment: @chadnt, just to clarify I meant that it was unrelated to any of the existing schema, etc.  They want to start storing a new "characteristic" that I haven't accommodated, for lack of a better explanation.  Anyway... it sounds like it ought to work with only a little anxiety ;)

Comment: If you are adding a table only once then using SSMS is a good idea.  Normally I create a text file and then drop the file into SSMS as a new query.  Not sure what you mean by update the site.  The only update you would need is if you where using Entity and had to refresh the mapping between the c# application and the database.

Comment: @jdweng yes, that's exactly what I mean.  I've never had to do that once I've gone live with a site.  I assume it's pretty simple but never having done it before it's a little scary ;)

Comment: I create databases all the time and add new tables.  It really isn't very difficult.

Comment: @jdweng I know, in theory... but doing it for the first time is making my palms sweat a little ;)